# How to get final price for not current customer?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, special-price

There is a special customer group named A which has it's own special catalog rules and group prices. I am going to display final price of another customer group named B for A users.
How can I get final price of another customer group which is not for the current user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$now = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->timestamp(time());
$websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
$customerGroup = 4;
$new = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule')->getRulePrice( $now, $websiteId, $customerGroup, $_productId);

var_dump($new);
```

Or :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($code, 'customer_group_code');

//get group price
$product->setCustomerGroupId($group->getId());
$price = $product->getGroupPrice();

//get main price
$product->setCustomerGroupId(null);
$price = $product->getPrice();
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326814/magento-get-product-price-given-a-customer-group/12538397#12538397)

Comment: Thanks. My answer was in the link you mentioned. I should call setCustomerGroupId for product object and get another customer group price.

Comment: I updated my answer, thanks